# Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: .//app/img/icons/facebook.svg

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript, img

Estoy haciendo una app en nativescript y al querer hacer un icono me da el sigueinte error:

> JS: Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.MalformedURLException: no
>   protocol: ./app/img/icons/facebook.svg

Mi archivo facebook.svg se encuentra en la siguiente ruta:

```
proyecto\src\app\img\icons
```

en mi archivo app.js

```
.fb-ico{
    background-image: url('./app/img/icons/facebook.svg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

login.component.html

```
<button class="fb-ico"></button>
```

estructura de mi app
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas tratando de descargar una imagen, si ves el mensaje de error indica:

> MalformedURLException: no protocol: ./app/img/icons/facebook.svg

el problema es que intenta descargar una imagen mediante el protocolo `https://` ( o `http://` ) y este no esta presente, ya que estas usando :

```
./app/img/icons/facebook.svg
```

La documentación de [NativeScript indica las posibles formas de cargar imagenes](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/images):

- Para URL (prefijo `http://` o `https://` )
- Para archivo local (prefijo  `~/`)
- Para recurso (prefijo `res://`)

---

Actualización:

**NativeScript no soporta graficos vectoriales .svg**

Comment: Ahora lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:  background-image: url('~/../app/img/icons/facebook.svg'); y ahora me dice lo siguiente: JS: Error in reading bitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/org.nativescript.workingreatapp/files/app/../app/img/icons/facebook.svg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @LuisHernandez cargalo usando res:// !

Comment: ya leí la documentación que me pasaste y no soporta .SVG y lo coloque como .PNG y reinicie el emulador y funcionó, al final quedo de esta manera: background-image: url('~/app/img/icons/facebook.png'); Muchas gracias!

Comment: @LuisHernandez no me había percatado usabas un gráfico vectorial :|